# How to speedup search result in excel VBA user-form?

Tags: excel, vba

the below codes are for search values from a list-box and data of list-box is connected to a sheet named (VEHICLE IN)
and the code is working, but it's take too much time and sometime also hung-up the excel. and also make excel to "not responding".
I don't know how to speed up my search facility.
and also did not fin an error.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 TextBox1.SetFocus
 lstSearchVehicle.ColumnCount = 23
         SearchVehicle.lstSearchVehicle.ColumnWidths = "15,35,55,50,50,60,60,50,50,0,0,60,60,60,0,60,60,40,35,60,45,60,60"
 lstSearchVehicle.List = Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Range("A1:W101" & Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
 TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
Private Sub lstSearchVehicle_Change()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next
 Dim j As Long, testString As String
 testString = "*" & TextBox1.Text & "*"
 With Me.lstSearchVehicle
 .List = Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Range("A1:W101" & Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
 If .ListIndex = -1 And Len(TextBox1.Text) Then
 For j = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
      If (Not (LCase(.List(j, 0)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 1)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 2)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 3)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 4)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 5)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 6)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 7)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 8)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 9)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 10)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 11)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 12)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 13)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 14)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 15)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 16)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 17)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 18)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 19)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 20)) Like testString) And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 21)) Like testString))) _
 And (Not (LCase(.List(j, 22)) Like testString)) Then .RemoveItem j
 Next j
 End If
 End With
     
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
 lstSearchVehicle_Change
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` instead of looping.

Comment: or bulk load the data into a variant array and loop that instead of looping ranges on the worksheet.

Comment: Sir plz can you o that for me. I don't know VBA.

Comment: Dear Scott Craner sir, how to bulk load data to variant array? I am newbies in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks a little odd.

Firstly, are you sure this range definition is the one you want? It's taking the last used row and prepending '101' to that row. So if you're last row is 12,345 then you're taking values from 10,112,345 rows.

```
Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Range("A1:W101" & Sheets("VEHICLE IN").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Secondly, are you aware that the listbox loading routine is being called whenever the textbox is changed? It might be what you want, but that could cause some hang-ups if your dataset is large. It's also not ideal to call an event handler routine manually - as you have done in your textbox event handler.

Thirdly, unless you really know what's going on 'under the hood' of your processor, it's not ideal removing items from an object that you're looping through.

All of the points above will either be causing your routine to be bigger than expected or you will find it difficult to track in those event handlers.

I'm not going to write your code for you, but it'd look something a bit more like this:

```
Private Const LISTBOX_COL_COUNT As Long = 23

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    PopulateListbox "*" & TextBox1.Text & "*"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = LISTBOX_COL_COUNT
        .ColumnWidths = "15,35,55,50,50,60,60,50,50,0,0,60,60,60,0,60,60,40,35,60,45,60,60"
    End With
    
    PopulateListbox
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateListbox(Optional removeItem As String = vbNullString)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim v() As Variant, listItems() As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Variant
    Dim rowList As Collection
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim itemText As String
    Dim isMatch As Boolean
    
    'Define the target range.
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, LISTBOX_COL_COUNT)
    End With
    
    'Read the values into an array.
    v = rng.Value2
    
    'If no removals are required then just populate with the read array.
    If removeItem = vbNullString Then
        ListBox1.List = v
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'For removals find the list of matching rows in the array.
    Set rowList = New Collection
    For r = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
        isMatch = False
        For c = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
            itemText = LCase(CStr(v(r, c)))
            If itemText Like removeItem Then
                isMatch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If isMatch Then rowList.Add r
    Next
    
    'Size the new list array, based on matching items.
    ReDim listItems(1 To rowList.Count, 1 To LISTBOX_COL_COUNT)
    
    'Copy the matchings rows to the new array.
    r = 1
    For Each rowNum In rowList
        For c = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
            listItems(r, c) = v(rowNum, c)
        Next
        r = r + 1
    Next
    
    'Populate the listbox with the new array.
    ListBox1.List = listItems
    
End Sub
```

Comment: User Form Load Quickly with data. But when i type something in textbox1, it gives me a runtime 9 error, subscript out of range, where ReDim is start (ReDim listItems(1 To rowList.Count, 1 To LISTBOX_COL_COUNT)
). In my Userform there is only two object available. 1 is TextBox1 and 2 is ListBox1. and data source is sheet1 Column Range A:W (Total 23 Column) with header line.

Comment: Yes, this is just skeleton code. You'll need to add the code that handles odd cases. That error indicates that there are no matches, so you'd need to handle the `rowList.Count = 0` case. I'm not sure if you're aware, but we don't write production code in these answers, we give you code that shows a principle. Try to understand each line of code and then adjust it to meet your needs.

Comment: Hats off, Mind blowing solution. I think this solution is the best and the fastest way to search values across a sheet. Really your are the Real Excel Master Mr. Ambie.

Comment: Thanks for giving the best solution @Ambie. A little issue i found (Actually this is not a real Issue). When I load the user form, the listbox columns widths are according to this value (ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "20,35,70,50,50,60,60,50,50,0,0,60,60,60,0,60,60,40,35,60,45,60,60"), But when search results loads, the columns widths may be changes to their defaults  value. Therefore some values are not visible clearly.